# How can I disable caret (focus, select) on li <tag> when click<ul>

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I'm used `<ul>` and `<li>` with custom `<ul>. <li>` class to display a custom checklist.
My problem is when clicking on `<ul>`(with CSS background:imageCheck) tag to change check or uncheck state. It also makes the caret focus on content of `<li>` tag.
How can I make the caret not to focus on `<li>` tag (`<li>` still need to editable).

[image]

Comment: Can we have some code? Try creating a snippet.

Comment: This is iOS related I guess

Comment: yes Martin, It make  keyboard show.

Comment: I'm just add CSS to <ul>tag like this if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf('ul') != -1)
    {
        node.setAttribute('class','imageCheckbox');
    }

Comment: hmmm... mouse cursor on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

There're special styles to disable text selection. Should work cross-browser:

```
ul, li {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=user-select